# I was trying to install Ubuntu but this popped up "Minimal bash-like line editing is supported."

Tags: system-installation, grub-legacy

I made a bootable flash drive from the Ubuntu .iso file ver 20.04.3 LTS With rufus on Windows 10. When I booted my PC From the flash drive this error popped up "Minimal bash-like line editing is supported.". Don't know what to do. I tried the same with Universal USB Tool or something but same. Please help he out. **Ubuntu isn't installed**. I saw in YouTube but they all are doing it in already *installed* one.

I've downloaded the iso form Ubuntu website and I already did it like 4 times.

Comment: Hey CyKrome! Can you please provide more details by [edit]ing your post? For example, in which OS you used Rufus to make bootable USB, did you [verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu), which YouTube videos you followed, which version of Ubuntu you are trying to install, etc.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO was valid?  as I'd guess the write to your media was flawed (if the validation of that didn't complete; which it sounds like it didn't)

Comment: @CyKrome there are instructions provided for verifying the ISO for macOS, windows and GNU/Linux (BSD users should already know how to do it I'd expect)

Comment: Thank You all for your help. My Installation has started